# Get options of an entity Field in twig

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity field that is passed to twig view, It is rendered and works fine.
Is it possible to get the `<option>` values of that field and render them somewhere else ( I need another select with the same values of that entity field >.
say this is my entity field

```
{{ form_widget(entity_field) }}
```

I want something like this

```
<select id="just_another_select">
 {% for value in entity_field.values %} <- how to get entity_field.values 
    <option > value </option> 
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can get all your options by accesing your field vars see this

```
{{ dump(form.YourFieldName.vars['choices']) }}
```

Comment: I don't think so I was running into a similar problem, I have dumped all my form fields to get it :D

Comment: oh the dump hangs my computer :D

Comment: You can find some documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#twig-reference-form-variables)