# How can I have a list of valid choices for the "choice" field and validator?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

The `choice` validator and the `choice` field type both accept an array of choices. However, each of them act on it a different way:

### The Choice Validator

The `choice` validator simply checks to see if the single-dimensional array contains a value (with something like `in_array()`). So, the array I should return from the function that is set as the `callback` of this validator should be something like this:

```
[
    'Open',
    'Closed'
]
```

### The Choice Field Type

This field type expects values in a different way. I need to pass the options as key-value pairs, with the keys becoming the value, and the values becoming the `innerText` of each `select` element:

```
[
    'Open' => 'Open',
    'Closed' => 'Closed'
]
```

### My Question

Now, my question is, how can I create a callback that would create the value that both of these (the `choice validator` and the `choice field type`) can use as-is?

### Update

If you look at the example provided at [Supplying the Choices with a Callback Function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#supplying-the-choices-with-a-callback-function), this is what I want to do. Except, having a callback such as the one provided in the example sets the values of my dropdown to `0`, `1`, and so on, instead of `male` and `female`.

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430139/get-options-of-an-entity-field-in-twig/29430320?noredirect=1#comment47040416_29430320

Comment: Not quite. I can't use such a thing with the `choice` validator.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. The `choice` field "autovalidates" himself: if you try to send a value that is not included in the field `choices`, it will trigger a validation error, without needing a specific validator.

The `choice` validator should be used when the field isn't a field of type `choice`

Comment: I need the validation as well because the user can change the field without going through a form (I.E. without using the `choice` field type). Plus, not putting in the validator would mean I might make a mistake myself when setting the value manually, and I will have to go and change the `setter` for the field to prevent that, too.

Comment: No, you don't. The user can not avoid the form, cause you're using it in the action with `$form->handleRequest($request)`, and if he messes up with the HTML client-side, he will not make a difference.

Comment: No. What I mean is, this is not the only way the user can input a value. I also provide a `REST` API, and he can send a request through that, too.